# Slide in & Slide out animation

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I am trying to make a slide in & out animation with c# & WPF.

So far I have managed to code the next lines:

XAML:

```
<Grid Name="grid" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
       <Border Name="border" Background="Red"></Border>
</Grid>
```

c#:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            border.Height = grid.ActualHeight;
            if (!isOpen) {
                isOpen = true;
                DoubleAnimation db = new DoubleAnimation();
                db.From = 0;
                db.To = grid.ActualHeight;
                db.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5);
                border.BeginAnimation(Grid.HeightProperty, db);
            } else {
                isOpen = false;
                DoubleAnimation db = new DoubleAnimation();
                db.From = grid.ActualHeight;
                db.To = 0;
                db.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5);
                border.BeginAnimation(Grid.HeightProperty, db);
            }
        }
```

The good thing is that the animation is executed. The bad thing is that this animation has the wrong effect, i mean the animation goes from top to middle and bottom to middle (like if it was shrinking)...

How can i make (or modify in my actual code) the slide effect(top to bottom & bottom to top)?

It has to be in c# code.

Comment: You can't use xaml to handle the animations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to *translate* your UI control so use a `TranslateTransform` (`Canvas.Top` is possible if you are on a canvas, but inefficient).

Modify your XAML to include a render transform set to a `TranslateTransform` object:

```
<Grid Name="grid" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" ClipToBounds="true">
    <Border Name="border" Background="Red">
       <Border.RenderTransform>
           <TranslateTransform x:Name="borderTransform"/>
       </Border.RenderTransform>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

And animate the `Y` property of the transform:

```
DoubleAnimation db = new DoubleAnimation();
db.From = 0;
db.To = grid.ActualHeight;
db.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5);
borderTransform.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.YProperty, db);
```

Just so you know, doing this is a *whole* lot cleaner using a `Storyboard` object (plus you can set it up in XAML!)

Comment: Thank you for your anwser, how could i code this behavior on XAML?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I am getting the next error in the XAML: The member "Name" is not recognized or is not accesible: "<TranslateTransform Name="borderTransform"/>"

Comment: @FernandoSantiago You may have to use x:Name instead. You can also access it via the `Border` objects properties, its just a bit cleaner this way.

Comment: @FernandoSantiago I would ask a new question for the XAML version (though its probably a dupe). Just so you know, RenderTransform property paths are a bit tricky :(

Comment: @FernandoSantiago Try setting `ClipToBounds="true"` on the `Grid`