# Form slide transition C#

Tags: c#, winforms, transition

Im creating a transition for my form in Visual Studio,
i'm coding a slide effect for the width but it ends up to slow
is there anyway to make it more faster?
btw here is the code :

```
`int check = 0;
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.button1.Text = "Hide";

        if (check == 0)
        {

            for (int i = 350; i <= 824; ++i)
            {
                this.Size = new Size(i, 507);
                Thread.Sleep(10);
                this.CenterToScreen();


            }
            check = 1;


        }

        else if (check == 1)
        {
            this.button1.Text = "Key";

            for (int i = 824; i >= 351; i--)
            {
                this.Size = new Size(i, 507);
                Thread.Sleep(5);
                this.CenterToScreen();


            }


            check = 0;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Use built-in animations. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33114198/slide-in-slide-out-animation

Comment: @SvSv he is using winforms not wpf

Comment: If your monitor has a refresh rate of 60 Hz, then changes faster than 16.667 ms can not be displayed anyway. Use a timer with lager intervalls and bigger size steps `for (int i = 824; i >= 351; i += 10)`

Comment: by any chances, should i change my code?

Comment: Change ++i and i-- to i+=2 and i-=2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using your existing code, you can tune it for the sake of speed like;

```
private int check = 0;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.button1.Text = "Hide";

    if (check == 0)
    {
        for (int i = 350; i <= 824; i += 2)
        {
            this.Size = new Size(i, 507);
            Thread.Sleep(1);
            this.CenterToScreen();
        }
        check = 1;


    }

    else if (check == 1)
    {
        this.button1.Text = "Key";

        for (int i = 824; i >= 351; i -= 2)
        {
            this.Size = new Size(i, 507);
            Thread.Sleep(1);
            this.CenterToScreen();
        }
        check = 0;
    }
}
```

You can change Thread.Sleep lines as above and increase or decrease the loop variables for faster an animation.